# Is it possible to download a folder/directory using spring-cloud-config server's end points?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry, spring-cloud-config-server

I am using Jhipster registry as a Eureka server and spring-cloud-config. We have one GIT repo which is mapped to the spring-cloud-config server and in that GIT repo I have a folder named **templates** which has list of **.html** files.

As I get to know it is not possible to access those **.html** files through spring-cloud-config server's end points, is it possible to download the complete **templates** folder programatically in spring boot application using registry(spring-cloud-config) end points ?

I am planning to download that **templates** folder and store it somewhere so that it could be  available for my other microservice

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you read the doc I pointed you to in you other very similar topic? What did not work to make you say " I get to know it is not possible to access those .html files through spring-cloud-config server"? It would be nice to at least reply to those who took time to comment your initial question before opening a new very similar one.

Comment: Hi @GaëlMarziou I did tried the doc you suggested and I was having some issues with it and yes I agree, I should have first replied to your comment stating the issue I faced, before posting this question, my sincere apologies for not doing that. And I was also curious to know if there is any way to download a resources folder/directory from spring cloud config server, when I googled about it I didn't found anything, that's why I posted this question before replying to your comment.